# Find the maximum vertical distances (and the corresponding x value) between 2 accumulate curves

Tags: python, distance, curve

I have 2 lists of tuples and they form 2 curves. The length of the lists is not necessarily the same.

```
list1 = [(100,3), (101,4)...,(159, 21)]
list2 = [(102,2), (105,3)...,(153, 21)]
```

to plot them out:

```
x_val_1 = [x[0] for x in list1]
y_val_1 = [x[1] for x in list1]

x_val_2 = [x[0] for x in list2]
y_val_2 = [x[1] for x in list2]
```

[image: see how the curves look like]

These two lists of tuples across at least once. I want to find the maximum distance between the curves within each phase. eg. I want to know the x-value around 108, 125 and 150 where there are the maximum vertical distances between these curves.

Can someone help me to solve this question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to find the maximum distance between curves for points that exist in both? Because then you'd need to interpolate and find the values of `y1(x2)` and `y2(x1)`, add them to your existing lists, and work from there.

Comment: @Guimoute. Thanks for your comment. No, it's not necessary that the x exists in both lists. Say, there could be an x-value around 108 where the vertical distance between the 2 curves is the max, and does not exist in either list. The difficult part for me is how to find such x value. Do you get some idea?

Comment: There are certainly other ways, but I would just build a `X` list that's equal to `x_val_1 ∪ x_val_2`, expand `y1` and `y2` lists with interpolation so that they have as many elements as `X`, and then calculate a distance list `= [abs(y2[n] - y1[n]) for n in range(len(X))]`. Then you can find the index where that list reaches a maximum, and the associated x value is just `X[that index]`.

Comment: Thanks, I will try the way you suggested!

Comment: ..However, that doesn't solve the other question that I want to find the maximum distance within different phases that determined by how many times the curves cross. I got more than 500 curves pairs so that manual selection is not an ideal way for me

Comment: You can determine when the curves cross by checking whether y2-y1 has changed sign. You could even have an entire list of signs and for each "iso sign" sub-list you search the max distance.

Comment: Thanks for reminding!

Comment: On a technical note: you're not showing two curves. You're showing two polygons. Also it sounds like you're not looking for a true maximum distance, you're only looking for maximum _vertical_ distance, e.g. the maxima on the function |f(x) - g(x)|.

Comment: I am not sure if we should call them polygons, as polygons are supposed to be closed graph.